# SQL UPDATE for specific user session

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I can add and delete the data I want to/from a db for a specific user, based on the session ID however, when I try to update the data for that specific user, I get an error. That duplicate key statement doesn't work properly either because the key is set to record ID vs stock's symbol. Any idea how to resolve that because now when a person tries to add the same stock twice, they are allowed to do so and so this leads to issues later on. Not sure if I'm going about this the correct way now with that Update statement instead, for the update part, so I'd appreciate any feedback/help. Thanks!

Code for INSERT & UPDATE:

```
// When the Buy button is pressed, specific action will be triggered according to the input given.
    if(isset($_POST['Buy']))
    { 
        // Checking whether first line is completely filled.
        if(empty($_POST['sym1']) or empty($_POST['pri1']) or empty($_POST['q1']))
        {
            ?><h2><center>To add values, please fill out at least the first row completely.</center></h2><?php
        // die();
    }
    // Loop through the form to allow for an appropriate db update.
    for($x=1;$x<=4;$x++)
    {
        $sym = [];
        $pri = [];
        $q = [];
        // If input provided is correct then update the db.
        if (!empty($_POST['sym'.$x]) and !empty($_POST['pri'.$x]) and !empty($_POST['q'.$x])) 
        {
            $sym[$x] = $_POST['sym'.$x];
            $pri[$x] = $_POST['pri'.$x];
            $q[$x] = $_POST['q'.$x];
            $memberid = $_SESSION['memberID'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO portfolio2 
                (stocks_symbol, price, quantity, memberID)
                VALUES ('$sym[$x]', $pri[$x], $q[$x], $memberid)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                price=$pri[$x], quantity=$q[$x]";

            // Check if values are added successfully and if so, then display a message to the user.
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
            {
                ?><h2><center><?php
                echo "Stocks added successfully!";
                ?></h2><center><?php
            }
            else
            {
                ?><h2><center><?php
                echo "Error- Stocks weren't added!". "<br>". $sql.
                "<br>". $conn->error;
                ?></h2><center><?php
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
// UPDATE 
    elseif(isset($_POST['Update']))
{
    // Check to see whether the stock symbol has been provided
    if(empty($_POST['sym1']))
    {
        ?><h2><center>To update values, please enter the symbol of the stock to be updated.</center></h2><?php
        // die();
    }

    // Loop through the form to allow for an appropriate db update.
    for($x=1;$x<=4;$x++)
    {
        $sym = [];
        $pri = [];
        $q = [];

        // When all three values to be updated are given and are correct, update the db accordingly.
        if (!empty($_POST['sym'.$x]) and !empty($_POST['pri'.$x]) and !empty($_POST['q'.$x])) 
        {
            $sym[$x] = $_POST['sym'.$x];
            $pri[$x] = $_POST['pri'.$x];
            $q[$x] = $_POST['q'.$x];
            $memberid = $_SESSION['memberID'];
            $sql = "UPDATE portfolio2 SET price=$pri[$x] and quantity=$q[$x] WHERE stocks_symbol='$sym[$x]' and memberid=$memberid";

            // Check to see whether the values are updated successfully and if so, then display a message to the user.
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
            {
                ?><h2><center><?php
                echo "Stocks updated successfully!";
                ?></h2><center><?php
            }
            else
            {
                ?><h2><center><?php
                echo "Error- Couldn't update stocks from the table". "<br>". $sql.
                "<br>". $conn->error;
                ?></h2><center><?php
            }
        }   
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Table structure:
portfolio2

```
CREATE TABLE `portfolio2` (
 `stockID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `stocks_symbol` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `price` decimal(30,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `quantity` int(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `memberid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`stockID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: What is the error message?  (append the message to the bottom of the question, and **not** as a comment)

Comment: Actually, I managed to get rid of the error and the update appears to go through but it doesn't update anything. In the db, price changes to 0 no matter what I type and quantity stays the same. What I get from a var_dump($sql)- string(84) "UPDATE portfolio2 SET price=3 and quantity=3 WHERE stocks_symbol='f' and memberid=22"
Stocks updated successfully!

Comment: The `SET` clause in your `UPDATE` statement is not correct. The fields that you `SET` should be separated by comma's, not and, so: `SET price=$pri[$x] and quantity=$q[$x]` ... should instead be: `SET price=$pri[$x], quantity=$q[$x]`

Comment: That's great, thank you! It's working now. As for the other question, do you have an idea of how to make it so that a specific user can't add the same stock twice? I tried it so that the stock symbol is the key but then that blocks other users from adding it too... Maybe some type of IF statement for that INSERT statement is needed? Just not sure how to implement it in this case...

Comment: That could potentially be covered at the table level, but you'll need to append the table structure to the bottom of the question. (do not add as another comment)   You can get this info by running a `SHOW CREATE TABLE portfolio2` query.  Copy/paste that output to the end of your question.

Comment: Looks like @Jacobian has already provided what would have been my next response as an answer. (go ahead and accept that if it works for you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent users from adding the same stock twice, you can do it by creating a `UNIQUE` index:

```
ALTER TABLE `portfolio2` ADD UNIQUE `unique_idx`(`memberid`, `stocks_symbol`);
```

Comment: This does solve the issue but only if I get rid of the 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' statement, which is fine, thank you. Also, the above solution actually allows me to update w/o having to have the separate UPDATE statement but I actually prefer it that way so I'm going to leave it as it is now. Once again, thanks!